# fstream for output on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

Updating computer from Windows XP to Windows 7. Both reading and writing files worked on XP. But on 7 just the reading works not writing. Also using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Writing binary file does not work on Windows 7 creating the file:

```
fstream fp("c:\\foo.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);

fp.write((char *)vpds[globalTarget],VPD_SIZE);
fp.flush();
fp.close();
```

Reading works on both OS:

```
fstream fp(c:\\fooMe.bin, ios::in | ios::binary);
fp.read((char *)vpd,VPD_SIZE);
if (fp.gcount() ==0)
   return FILE_ERROR;
fp.close();
```

Comment: "just the reading works not writing" this almost sounds like an access rights issue. Try to use a directory where you clearly have access rights or start VisualStudio with administrator rights.

Comment: I agree with Dyp. The permissions are enforced more in Windows7 then they were in windows xp. I know this might sound strange, but right click and see what you user permission is for writing to drive C:\ root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are right: the root directory is not the location to store user files, and Windows 7 enforces that. Use the user's profile directory (My Documents/AppData as appropriate).

Comment: Yes I move the write file to "c:\\users\\public\\documents\\foo.bin" I found a couple of strange behaviors with 7. 

1) if I double click on the exe it does create the file.
2) if a function is called from main() it will NOT create the file  
3) if I use the debug option on Visual Studio 2008 it will not create the file in main()

Also open all permission and "run as admin"

If anyone out there has VS 2008 or higher can you please test "programming 101"  Thanks